# install cocoapods library with specific name

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I want to install pod file with the specific name

Now, if I fire the command ***pod install*** 
It will create the project with the name of Pods that I don't want.

It should be like, Suppose I installed Google Map library from CocoaPods command, then It should create a project name like Google Map

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods doesn't let you pick the name of an existing pod. If you want you can fork the pod and edit the Podspec, or [write your own Podspec](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html).